# How do you check to see if two different file reference "strings" refer to the same file?

Tags: c, file, compare

We have a function in straight C that is intended to tell us if two file references refer to the same file.  Right now it first checks to see if the passed in parameters are actually the same pointer, and if not, it looks at the characters to see if the strings of characters are the same.  But that doesn't account for the possibility of different ways to refer to the same file.  For example...

"/d1/d2/d3/theFile" compared to "../d3/theFile"

Those could be the same file or not, depending on the directory structure and where the current point of reference is.  I'd like to improve the following function to be able to check to see if the string reference to a file refers to the same file as another string...

```
static bool is_same_file (const char *f1, const char *f2) {
    if (f1==f2)
        return true;
    return (0==strcmp(f1,  f2));
}
```

I imagine that it might be possible to try opening both files and use that in some way.  But I don't know how to check to see if the opened files are the same physical file on the drive, and not just coincidentally the same file that happen to exist in different directories.  In C#, there's a FileInfo class that can be used to find a file based on that reference string, and then you can compare complete directory information, file name, and so on.  Is there a way to do something similar in C?

Comment: I don't think there are any OS-independent ways. On Unix you can use `stat()` and check that `st_dev` and `st_ino` are the same.

Comment: POSIX has the `realpath` function to return the canonicalized, absolute pathname of a pathname. That sounds similar to what you describe for the C# `FileInfo` class's ability to get the full pathname.

Comment: @IanAbbott  [`realpath()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/realpath.html) is only guaranteed to return "***an*** absolute pathname that names the same file, whose resolution does not involve '.', '..', or symbolic links."  A file with multiple hard links will have more than one absolute path name.  There is no "canonical" path name in POSIX systems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On a POSIX system you can use `stat()` to check if they have the same inode number on the same filesystem.

You should also check the generation number, to handle a race condition due to the file being deleted and a new file getting its inode number between the two calls.

```
#include <sys/stat.h>

static bool is_same_file (const char *f1, const char *f2) {
    struct stat s1, s2;
    if (stat(f1, &s1) < 0)) {
        perror("stat f1");
        return false;
    }
    if (stat(f2, &s2) < 0)) {
        perror("stat f2");
        return false;
    }
    return s1.st_dev == s2.st_dev && s1.st_ino == st.st_ino && s1.st_gen == s2.st_gen;
}
```

Comment: This looks promising.  I'll try it out and I'll mark this as the answer.  Thank you for the information!

Comment: This seems to do what I need.  I need to fiddle a little with what pieces get tested though.  Something that should have come back as the same file didn't.  But this definitely set me on the right path.  Thank you @Barmar

Comment: What else did you need to test?

Comment: If this isn't really correct, you should post a more correct answer. I shouldn't get the reputation just because I set you in the right direction.

Comment: Are there any issues with NFS or other remotely-mounted filesystems?

Comment: @SteveSummit There's a theoretical race condition if filesystem mounts change between the two calls, so the same fsid refers to different physical filesystems. But the chance that this will happen *and* the inode and generation numbers are the same is negligible unless someone is purposely tying to make two files seem to be the same.

Comment: They would need have fine control over the inode tables on the two filesystems, and precise timing.

Comment: There's probably issues with remote filesystems that don't implement the full semantics of Unix filesystems. E.g. they might have to synthesize inode numbers that don't actually exist.

Comment: *You should also check the generation number, to handle a race condition due to the file being deleted and a new file getting its inode number between the two calls.*  How many times should you do that?  ;-)  Because the answer is invalid the moment it's returned.  You could `open()` the files, use `fstat()` to check the inode and device numbers, then close the files.  And the answer would still be, "They  ***were*** the same when the check was made".

Comment: @AndrewHenle Good point. What you really should do is open the files, call fstat, and then use the opened file descriptors so it can't change after testing.

Comment: However, if this is just a sanity check, you may not need to handle every contingency. E.g. `cp foo bar` will abort if they're the same file, but I don't know how well it avoids race conditions.

Comment: I'm sorry to have left the conversation for so long.  This was a sanity check that was previously being handled as a string comparison to see if the paths were the same, but as was mentioned, multiple paths can reach the same file.  Sadly, because this was so long ago, I don't remember where in the code this was and can't find the slight adjustments I needed.